# How to convert a stringified value (from JS) into a List in Java using Gson?

Tags: java, gson

I have this value that is being passed as a string `"[\"value0\"]"`
I want to derive the following `List<String>`, `["value0"]`

How to do that using Java and Gson?

What I have tried is following and is not working:

```java
ArrayList<String> values = gson.fromJson(stringifiedList, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){ }.getType());
```

EDIT: the error message is:

```
Request processing failed: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $] with root cause
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly that and it appears to work:

```
String stringifiedList = "[\"value0\"]";

List<String> array = gson.fromJson(stringifiedList, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){ }.getType());

System.out.println(array);
```

Output

```
[value0]
```

It doesn't effect the functionality but it is better practice to use `TypeToken<List<String>>` than `TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: well i am getting Request processing failed: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $] with root cause

Comment: I’ll need to see more code